# Google script unresponsive - Google sheets GUI

Tags: google-apps-script

There is a code that an ex-coworker and I worked on to optimize a google sheet. 
It uses google script and HTML to create a custom menu and Form to collect or recall data from lines in a google sheet (Sheet 1). 
Functionally it worked well as of 2/29/2020. The form will pop up, however, data can no longer be pulled from the sheet (sheet 1) nor will data be sent to the same sheet. 
[Custom Menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGlKe.png)
[Custom form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw12m.png)

Code

```
    //The toolbar menu
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Create New 8D', functionName: 'createNew_'},
    {name: 'Update', functionName: 'update_'}

  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('8D Menu', menuItems);
}


//Call function pop-up to Create New
function createNew_() {
  var html = doGet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Create New');
}

//google apps scripts get row by column value
function findInColumn(column, data) {

  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var column = sheet.getRange(column + ":" + column);  // like A:A

  var values = column.getValues(); 
  var row = 0;

  while ( values[row] && values[row][0] != data ) {
    row++;
  }

  if (values[row][0] == data) {

    return row+1;
  }else {
    return -1;
  }

}


//Create a Data Entry Form
function doGet() {
  var result = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Form')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  result.setHeight(600);
  result.setWidth(800)
  return result;
}

//Retrieves data from the return form and fills the spreadsheet
function getValuesFromForm(form){

  var customer = form.customer,
      scar_id = form.scar_id,
      issue_date = form.issue_date,
      eight_d_tat = form.eight_d_tat,
      problem_statement = form.problem_statement,
      leader = form.leader,
      sponsor = form.sponsor,
      business_root_cause = form.business_root_cause,
      impact = form.impact,
      occurence = form.occurence,
      detection = form.detection,
      closed_date = form.closed_date,
      d3_due = form.d3_due,
      d5_due = form.d5_due,
      d7_due = form.d7_due,
      d3_sent = form.d3_sent,
      d5_sent = form.d5_sent,
      d7_sent = form.d7_sent,
      cqe = form.cqe,
      cust_actions = form.cust_actions,
      fab_actions = form.fab_actions,
      loc = form.loc,
      tech = form.tech,
      mrb = form.mrb,
      mrb1 = form.mrb1,
      auto = form.auto,      
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  //Import data into the spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(customer);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(Scar_ID);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(eight_d_tat);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(problem_statement);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(issue_date);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 7).setValue(closed_date);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 8).setValue(business_root_cause);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 9).setValue(d3_due);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 10).setValue(d5_due);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 11).setValue(d7_due);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 12).setValue(d3_sent);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 13).setValue(d5_sent);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 14).setValue(d7_sent);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 15).setValue(cqe);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 16).setValue(leader);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 17).setValue(sponsor);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 18).setValue(cust_actions);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 19).setValue(fab_actions);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 20).setValue(loc);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 21).setValue(tech);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 22).setValue(mrb);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 23).setValue(mrb1);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 24).setValue(auto);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 27).setValue(impact);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 28).setValue(occurence);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 29).setValue(detection);
}

function getValuesFromSheet(form){
  var row = findInColumn('A',form.gf_8d_number);
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var obj = {};

  obj.fieldKey = {};
  obj.keyField = {};
  obj.values = {};

  //mappings

  var lf = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  for(x in lf){
    obj.fieldKey[lf[x].replace(' ','_').toLowerCase()] = x;
    obj.keyField[x] = lf[x].replace(' ','_').toLowerCase();
  }

  //values
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  obj.rowo = rowValues[2]; 

  //obj.kf = [];

  for(f in obj.keyField){
    var v = rowValues[f];

    obj.values[obj.keyField[f]] = v+'';
  }



  return obj;


}


function getColumnMappings(form){
  var row = findInColumn('A',form.gf_8d_number);
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  //var obj = {};
  //obj.sheet = sheet;
  //obj.test = form.gf_8d_number;
  //obj.rowo = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0][1];
  //sheet.getRange(row, column).setValues(values)
  //obj.customer = form.customer;


  //obj.firstrow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var fields = {};
  var lf = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  for(x in lf){
    fields[lf[x].replace(' ','_').toLowerCase()] = x;

  }

  //for(sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())

  return fields;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that there is no issue with the code. I had another user changed a few sheet attributes. 
The code works perfectly.